# navigation routing isn't working properly

Tags: flutter, dart, navigation, supabase, supabase-database

so i have a splash that redirect the user according to info available in the database (if a data is available in the database it will redirect the user to home page, otherwise to personal info page where he fills up his information), here is how it looks :

```
 import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:meta_gym/main.dart';
import 'package:meta_gym/views/onBorading/login.dart';
import 'package:meta_gym/views/onBorading/personal_info.dart';
import 'package:supabase_flutter/supabase_flutter.dart';

class SplashScreen extends StatefulWidget {
  const SplashScreen({super.key});

  @override
  State<SplashScreen> createState() => _SplashScreenState();
}

class _SplashScreenState extends State<SplashScreen> {
  User? _user;

  Future _getAuth() async {
    setState(() {
      _user = supabaseClient.auth.currentUser;
});
supabaseClient.auth.onAuthStateChange.listen((event) {
  if (mounted) {
    setState(() {
      _user = event.session?.user;
    });
  }
});
  }

  @override
  void initState() {
    _getAuth();

    super.initState();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return _user == null
        ? const LogIn()
        : FutureBuilder(
            future: checkUserInfo(_user),
            builder: (context, snapshot) {
              if (snapshot.connectionState == ConnectionState.none) {
                return const Scaffold(body: Text('NO INTERNET CONNECTION'));
              } else if (snapshot.connectionState == ConnectionState.waiting) {
                return const Scaffold(
                    body: Center(child: CircularProgressIndicator()));
              } else if (snapshot.hasError) {
                print(snapshot.error);
            //maybe internet errors
                return Scaffold(
                  body: Center(child: Text('${snapshot.error}')),
                );
              } else {
            final response = snapshot.data;

            if (response.containsKey('goal') && response['goal'] != null) {
              print(response['goal']);
              return const HomePage();
            } else {
              return const PersonalInfo();
            }
          }
        },
      );
  }
}
//if the user confirms his email not using the same phone it will not redirect him directly,             
WORK ON THIS

//(try using pop until, and see if it's possible to check if the user is authinticated)

Future checkUserInfo(User? user) async {

print("method called **************************************************");

final response = supabaseClient
  
.from('user_info')
  
.select('goal')
  .eq('id', user?.id)
  .single();

return response;

}
```

the thing is when i get redirected to personalInfo page i have to fill some info and then go to another screen where i have to add some more info and then register the info and navigate back to home screen when the info get registered successfully, here is the on tap method responsible for this :

```
                      setState(() {
                        _isLoading = true;
                      });

                      if (await checkInternetConnection()) {
                        final userId = supabaseClient.auth.currentUser?.id;
                        // calculate the user's BMR
                        late double bmr;

                        switch (widget.gender) {
                          case 1:
                            bmr = (88.362 +
                                (13.397 * widget.weight) +
                                (4.799 * widget.height) -
                                (5.677 * widget.age));
                            break;
                          case 2:
                            bmr = (447.593 +
                                (9.247 * widget.weight) +
                                (3.098 * widget.height) -
                                (4.330 * widget.age));
                        }

                        // determine the user's calories needed in a day
                        late double caloriesNeeded;
                        switch (widget.activityLevel) {
                          case 1:
                            caloriesNeeded = bmr * 1.2;
                            break;
                          case 2:
                            caloriesNeeded = bmr * 1.375;
                            break;
                          case 3:
                            caloriesNeeded = bmr * 1.55;
                            break;
                          case 4:
                            caloriesNeeded = bmr * 1.725;
                            break;
                          case 5:
                            caloriesNeeded = bmr * 1.9;
                            break;
                          default:
                            caloriesNeeded = bmr * 1.55;
                        }

                        // sets the user goal of daily intake
                        late double caloricTarget;
                        switch (userGoalValue) {
                          case 1:
                            caloricTarget = caloriesNeeded * 0.85;
                            break;
                          case 2:
                            caloricTarget = caloriesNeeded;
                            break;
                          case 3:
                            caloricTarget = caloriesNeeded * 1.08;
                            break;
                          default:
                            caloricTarget = caloriesNeeded;
                        }

                        try {
                          final response = await supabaseClient
                              .from("user_info")
                              .update({
                                'age': widget.age,
                                'height': widget.height,
                                'weight': widget.weight,
                                'gender': widget.gender,
                                'goal': userGoalValue,
                                'activity_level': widget.activityLevel,
                                'bmr': bmr,
                                'calories_level': caloriesNeeded,
                                'caloric_target': caloricTarget
                              })
                              .match({'id': userId})
                              .select('goal')
                              .single();
                          print(response);

                          if (mounted) {
                            setState(() {
                              _isLoading = false;
                            });
                          }

                          if (response.containsKey('goal') &&
                              response['goal'] != null) {
                            print(response['goal']);
                            Navigator.of(context).push(MaterialPageRoute(
                              builder: (context) => const HomePage(),
                            ));
                          }

                          showDialog(
                            barrierDismissible: false,
                            barrierColor: Colors.transparent,
                            context: context,
                            builder: (context) {
                              return const CheckDialog(
                                  color: Colors.grey,
                                  title: "SUCCESS",
                                  imagePath:
                                      "lib/assets/json_images/check_mark.json");
                            },
                          );
                          Navigator.of(context)
                              .popUntil((route) => route.isFirst);
                        } catch (error) {
                          if (mounted) {
                            setState(() {
                              _isLoading = false;
                            });
                          }

                          showDialog(
                            barrierDismissible: false,
                            barrierColor: Colors.transparent,
                            context: context,
                            builder: (context) {
                              return const CheckDialog(
                                  color: Colors.grey,
                                  title: 'SOMETHING WENT WRONG',
                                  imagePath:
                                      "lib/assets/json_images/error_mark.json");
                            },
                          );
                        }
                      } else {
                        setState(() {
                          _isLoading = false;
                        });
                        showDialog(
                          barrierDismissible: false,
                          barrierColor: Colors.transparent,
                          context: context,
                          builder: (context) {
                            return const CheckDialog(
                                color: Colors.grey,
                                title: "NO INTERNET",
                                imagePath:
                                    "lib/assets/json_images/no_wifi.json");
                          },
                        );
                      }
                    },
```

but for some reason when the info are registered i don't get redirected to home screen but rather get sent to personal info page again as if am using .popUntil(), why is that? and how can i fix this?

Comment: you can try with creating future variable instead of `uture: checkUserInfo(_user),` You can follow [doc](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/FutureBuilder-class.html) example